# Problem accessing Worksheetfunction routines

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to run WorksheetFunction.Search and WorksheetFunction.Find in VBA (Microsoft 365, EXCEL 2010) but get "unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class".

Is there an add-in I need?

BTW: WorksheetFunction.Text works fine.

Comment: No, you don't need an add-in. But you must pass the arguments correctly both in sequence, number and data type. Consider using VBA's own Find function instead of invoking Excel's.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your code. The error description doesn't match (pun intended) the first part of your sentence. That said, normally one uses `InStr` or maybe `StrComp` instead of worksheet functions.